# how to get column specific unique values in data.table in r

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table say 'dt' it looks like:

```
head(time_info_summary)
mon_from_time mon_to_time tue_from_time tue_to_time wed_from_time wed_to_time thu_from_time thu_to_time
0700        2200          0700        2200          0700        2200          0700        2200
0800        2200          0800        2200          0800        2200          0800        2200
0800        2200          0800        2200          0800        2200          0800        2200
0700        2300          0700        2300          0700        2300          0700        2300
0800        2200          0800        2200          0800        2200          0800        2200
0800        2000          0800        2000          0800        2000          0800        2000
```

I want to have only the unique values in each of the column . for example my column "mon_from_time" must have only two records 0700 and 0800, column "mon_to_time" must have three records 2200 and 2300 and 2000 and so on.

How to do this ?

Comment: How are you going to handle having different numbers of unique values in each column?

Comment: I want to do comparison with the unique values of each column

Comment: You might want to edit your question to describe the comparison you intend to do. Because what you are asking at the moment seems impractical in a rectangular dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're looking for

```
apply(time_info_summary, 2, unique)
```

But as @thelatemail said, it's kind of impractical in a rectangular dataset setting.

Comment: and how can I also put the total count for each period . for example: 0700 - 2 times, 0800 - 4 times for monday in the same list

Comment: I think `apply(time_info_summary, 2, table)` should work.

Comment: Thanks that helped

Comment: Isn't this a data.table question? This should be `time_info_summary[, lapply(.SD, unique)]`. Also, please don't use `apply` on anything except a matrix. You could just do `lapply(time_info_summary, unique)` or such.